# Error when loading matplotlib in Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

Below is what happens when I try to "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt" using Anaconda Python. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Charles

--------------Here is what I tried-------------

I have: C:\Users\Charles\Anaconda;C:\Users\Charles\Anaconda\Scripts
in my path. and I did:

```
C:\>conda update conda -f
Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: ..............
Package plan for installation in environment C:\Users\Charles\Anaconda:

The following packages will be downloaded:

        package                    |            build
        ---------------------------|-----------------
        conda-4.0.5                |           py27_0         228 KB

    The following packages will be UPDATED:

        conda: 3.18.9-py27_0 --> 4.0.5-py27_0

    Proceed ([y]/n)? y

    Fetching packages ...
    conda-4.0.5-py 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00 430.59 kB/s
    [      COMPLETE      ]|##################################################| 100%
    Extracting packages ...
    [      COMPLETE      ]|##################################################| 100%
    Unlinking packages ...
    [      COMPLETE      ]|##################################################| 100%
    Linking packages ...
    [      COMPLETE      ]|##################################################| 100%

    C:\>conda update anaconda -f
    Fetching package metadata: ....
    Solving package specifications: .........

    Package plan for installation in environment C:\Users\Charles\Anaconda:

    The following packages will be downloaded:

        package                    |            build
        ---------------------------|-----------------
        anaconda-4.0.0             |      np110py27_0          16 KB

    The following packages will be UPDATED:

        anaconda: 2.4.1-np110py27_0 --> 4.0.0-np110py27_0

    Proceed ([y]/n)? y

    Fetching packages ...
    anaconda-4.0.0 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   2.35 MB/s
    [      COMPLETE      ]|##################################################| 100%
    Extracting packages ...
    [      COMPLETE      ]|##################################################| 100%
    Unlinking packages ...
    [      COMPLETE      ]|##################################################| 100%
    Linking packages ...
    [      COMPLETE      ]|##################################################| 100%

    C:\>python
    Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 28 2015, 16:44:52) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
    Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
    >>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Charles\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 29, in <module>
        import matplotlib.colorbar
      File "C:\Users\Charles\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py", line 34, in <module>
        import matplotlib.collections as collections
      File "C:\Users\Charles\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 27, in <module>
        import matplotlib.backend_bases as backend_bases
      File "C:\Users\Charles\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 62, in <module>
        import matplotlib.textpath as textpath
      File "C:\Users\Charles\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\textpath.py", line 18, in <module>
        from matplotlib.mathtext import MathTextParser
      File "C:\Users\Charles\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py", line 60, in <module>
        import matplotlib._png as _png
    ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
    >>>
```

Comment: Did you upgrade matplotlib after the numpy upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this, and then try to install matplotlib again.

```
conda install libpng
```